# Jasmin SMS Throttling Error

Tags: sms, throttling, smpp, kannel, jasmin-sms

I get a throttling error in Jasmin logs whenever i use SMPP connections lately.
Users connecting to my Jasmin server have Kannel servers.
Any thoughts? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is limit of throughput for each SMPP connector. Find out from connection provider and also update throughput parameter for each connector in smppccm to some fix value. By default it is unlimited that causes throttling error.